# Django Application: Foreign Key pointing to an abstract class

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to design a framework to help implement complex web flows. The framework would provide with abstract classes which could inherited and implemented by the sub-apps. Now, as you can see my abstract class Action has a Foreign Key with Stage. Since, it has a foreignkey it could not be made abstract due to which it would have its own table. So, If I have 2 implementing application then my first application can see all the Stages for itself as well as for the other application. I could make some tweaks in the queries to avoid this. But I want to know if there is solution so, that my implementing Action class could directly point to the Inheriting Stage class.

```
parent_app/models.py

class Stage(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Action(models.Model):
    stage = models.ForeignKey(Stage)
    class Meta:
       abstract = True
```

sub_app1/models.py

```
class StageImpl1(Stage):
    pass

class ActionImpl1(Action):
    ...
```

sub_app2/models.py

```
class StageImpl2(Stage):
    pass

class ActionImpl2(Action):
    ...
```

## Update:

The current situation is:

ActionImpl1 has a foreignkey to Stage

What I would to have is:

ActionImpl1 to have a foreignkey with StageImpl1

Comment: sorry what are you asking exactly? Django will not let you use a ForeignKey that points to an abstract class.. are you asking how you can work round this while keeping your "complex flows"? No one can answer this because you have provided no details about your needs and the code shown is very generic

Comment: Updated my question. Let me know if you need any other info

Comment: I have to say that this design isn't very pythonic - this kind of control flow through very abstract class hierarchies is more a Java thing - Python's dynamic features often allow you to design in a simpler manner.

Comment: "If I have 2 implementing application then my first application can see all the Stages for itself as well as for the other application" - are you sure about this? Each class that inherits from the abstract base class gets a seperate database table - how can one class see the relations of another? (or am I misunderstanding you?) I admit I've never created an abstract base class with a foreign key.

Comment: I know each class that inherits from abstract class gets a separate table. But my class Stage is not abstract which is why my implementing class can see all the stages. And how can I avoid that at the model relationship level is my question. I agree I am from Java ground and don't know python that well. Could you suggest me how I can use "Python's dynamic features to design in a simpler manner"

Comment: I'm not sure you really need to subclass `Stage`. The Django ORM will give you access to only the related objects of that class - not related objects of all the descendents of the parent class. So I don't think the problem you are thinking of even exists. I strongly suggest you do  a test implementation where you do not subclass `Stage` and use the python shell to see if the problem exists.

Comment: as for simplifying the design - I'm afraid no one can help you without in depth knowledge of the problem you are trying to solve. You approach does look unnecessarily complex for python. I'd suggest asking a new question where you explain the problem you are trying to solve, show the outline of your current design and ask if there's a simpler way (oh and mention you have a Java background so people don't think you're crazy :-)

Answer (score 7):

An abstract class is a class that doesn't exist. It is used as a basis for other classes. It is never never ever initialized.

Something that does not exist cannot have a foreign key pointing at it!

Something to look at, if you want to have a way to point at several different kinds of classes: [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations). This is Django's build-in way to have something that looks like a foreign key point at a number of different objects.

Comment: Excuse me for my obscurity. I know we can not use foreign key on abstract class. I have updated my question. Let me know if you need any other info

Comment: Obviously the class exists but no objects can be instantiated of it.

Answer (score 2):

It is imposible.
Think what would happen to all the classes with a foreign key pointing A if A is abtract and several classes inherit from A.

I dont know your requirements but I maybe you should consider using multitable inheritance, and point the FK to the parent table.

From the Django documentation:

Multi-table inheritance

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance

> The second type of model inheritance supported by Django is when each
>   model in the hierarchy is a model all by itself. Each model
>   corresponds to its own database table and can be queried and created
>   individually. The inheritance relationship introduces links between
>   the child model and each of its parents (via an automatically-created
>   OneToOneField). For example:

Comment: Updated my question. And I know what you are saying and this is what I am currently doing.